# Stop Background colour from filling DIV

Tags: css

I have an PNG image with a transparent area. It is a bit like a torn of checkout receipt with a zig-zag edge. It will sit at the bottom of a div with a white background to simulate a till receipt. I have tried this as follows.

```
 background: #ffffff url("../images/zigzag.png") bottom right no-repeat;
```

But the background white fills right to the edge of the image

[image]

Aside from creating another div is there a way to stop the background colour going under the image?

Comment: Do you want the green (surrounding) color visually "underneath" the jagged edge (so as to simulate the receipt laying on a green surface), or do you want the gray ("surface that the receipt rests on") to extend to the bottom of the page?

Comment: yes, green under the jagged edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another `div` is probably the cleanest solution.

However, if the height of your `div` is limited, you can instead make the background of the `div` transparent and extend the top of the "ragged-edge" image with white pixels until it's tall enough that it always provides a white background to the main part of the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

make background-color transparent:

```
#foo {
  background: transparent url(yourzig-zagImage) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```